# Magento slideshow not working

Tags: html, magento

i am using default magento rwd theme.

When i download the theme and run it in local the slideshow is not working and i have checked the source code. The slide show code itself is not there? 
How can i embed the slider code in homepage?

```
<?php   
$base_url=Mage::getBaseUrl();
$media_url=Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);?>


<div>
                <ul class="slideshow">
               <?php echo '<li><a href="'.$base_url.'accessories/eyewear.html"><img src="'.$media_url.'wysiwyg/slide-1.jpg" alt="An eye for detail - Click to Shop Eye Wear" /></a></li>'; ?>
               <?php echo '<li><a href="'.$base_url.'women.html"><img src="'.$media_url.'wysiwyg/slide-2.jpg" alt="Style solutions - covet-worthy styles in travel-friendly fabrics - Click to Shop Woman" /></a></li>'; ?>    
               <?php echo '<li><a href="'.$base_url.'men.html"><img src="'.$media_url.'wysiwyg/slide-3.jpg" alt="Wing man - hit the runway in stylish separates and casuals - Click to Shop Man" /></a></li>'; ?>


     </ul>
        <div class="slideshow-pager">&nbsp;</div>
<span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

How can i enable slide show as it is in the demo website?

Answer (score 0):

Call slide show page in cms home page. There will be an instruction to how to call slide show page in home page.

Comment: how can i call a html page ?